# Extracting Battery charge level in a connected bluetooth device using python in windows

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth

I am trying to use pybluez to get battery details of one of the connected bluetooth device. I could not understand how to extract them. Is it atleast possible to extract battery details using pybluez? if not which module of which programming language i can use to get the details?